# Printing Compose Semantics Tree to the Log

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I am following [Testing in Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-testing#3) Codelab but I am unable to print the **Semantics tree** using the `printToLog` function on a node. I am using this code inside the `androidTest` package.

```
import androidx.compose.ui.test.printToLog 

...

    //testing function
    @Test
    fun rallyTopAppBarTest() {
    
        val allScreen = RallyScreen.values().toList()
        testRule.setContent {
            //the component be tested in isolation goes here
            RallyTopAppBar(
                allScreens = allScreen,
                onTabSelected = {},
                currentScreen = RallyScreen.Accounts
            )
        }
        
        testRule.onRoot().printToLog("currentLabelExists")
        
            ....
    }
```

I have checked my LogCat with both **Debug** and **Verbose** filtering using `"currentLabelExists"` tag but the Semantics Tree is not printing on the log.

Any ideas on what I might be missing out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see the semantics tree.
Check if Android Studio Logcat has "No Filters"

[image: Filter options]

**Edit**
It seems to be a bug as I can sometimes see the logs even if I select "Show only selected application".

Comment: Hi Abhimanyu, Thx very much for pointing me to the right way. Why do u think the log is only shown when you don't have filters?

Comment: It seems to be a bug to me as I can sometimes see the logs even if I select "Show only selected application".  There are some inconsistencies.

Comment: Thx man, you are a legend.

Answer (score 2):

I know you are asking to log a test inside `androidTest`, but for anyone looking for a solution for `test`, the following might help.

If you try to print the compose semantics tree in a local test (a regular unit test that does not use an emulator), the method `printToLog` won't work as it logs into Logcat, which is Android-specific.

So the solution in my case was to create a new method like the following:

```
    fun SemanticsNodeInteraction.printToLog(
        maxDepth: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    ) {
        val result = "printToLog:\n" + printToString(maxDepth)
        println(result)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I just ran into the same problem:
The SemanticsTree seems to appear only when you run your tests in `Debug Mode`